# Generate UUID length of 35 char in JMeter

Tags: uuid, jmeter-4.0

I am trying to generate unique ID in Jmeter only for 35 char (length) But Jmeter {__UUDI()} function is creating 36 char (length) of unique ID. How Can I reduce the length?

Comment: Can you explain why you need it and how expected value be ?

Answer (score 0):

From jmeter reference of the UUID function, the UUID is a 128 bit random combination of values. This gets converted into a string of chars based on a rule assigning *n* bits to each character. Using ASCII, you should either get 32 or 36 chars. If 36 chars, you should get four dashes `-` in it. If you want 35 chars, you could try removing one dash.

I found [this](https://scion.duhs.duke.edu/vespa/project/wiki/DatabaseUuidEfficiency) a useful and clear reference.

Some more thoughts on UUIDs:

> A universally unique identifier (UUID) is a 128-bit number used to identify information in computer systems. The term globally unique identifier (GUID) is also used, typically in software created by Microsoft.
>
> [...]
>
> In its canonical textual representation, the 16 octets of a UUID are represented as 32 hexadecimal (base-16) digits, displayed in 5 groups separated by hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total of 36 characters (32 alphanumeric characters and 4 hyphens). - *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)*

What I'm suggesting is that you could use a non-canon representation like 8-8-4-12.